# NoClassDefFoundError loading a twain applet

Tags: java, class, applet, noclassdeffounderror, twain

I downloaded this Java app: http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/twain-scan.html

I did not attempt to compile, just downloaded the zip file and extracted into a "plugins" directory as instructed and then created this HTML:

```html
<html><body>
<applet id=scanx name=scanx code="Scan_.class" height="600" width="600" archive="plugins/Scan_.jar,plugins/uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jar"></applet>
<script type="text/javascript">
function scanit()
 {
   document.scanx.Scan_();
 }
</script> 
<input type=button onclick="scanit();">
</body></html>
```

I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` with `ij/plugin/PlugIn` in the dialog box. I've seen "plugin" and "ij" jar files in other Java apps, but putting them in the plugins folder and referencing them in the "archive" parameter does not seem to help.

I plead relative ignorance of Java, so it may be something obvious, but I've poked around with this a while with no luck figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You checked that `uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jar` contains `ij/plugin/PlugIn.class`?

Comment: Andrew, I looked in the jar file and there is no ij/plugin/PlugIn.class in there.  Nor in the Scan_.jar.  This is odd, since the "documentation" at the site I referenced in my original post seems to say I don't need anything else. I do have the ij.jar file which has that class in it.  I tried adding it to my archive parameter, after the mmscomputing one but still got the error. Since I appear to have that class in the ij.jar, what do you think might be the best course forward?

Comment: I've been hunting for open source / free and they are few and far between, each having different issues to contend with.  Are you saying I can't merge ij and the mms jar and sign the new jar?

Comment: No, I'm not saying you can't.  Try it.

Comment: I will when I get back to the office. I guess I should have phrased it "would it work if I merged them?"  Just trying to find a way to get it working is all.  Unfortunately, I know I'm operating outside my skill set, so just don't know what can, can't, will, or won't work.

Comment: Adding ij/plugin/PlugIn to the jar didn't change anything.  Back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: I cleared the java and browser caches and the merged jar worked just fine. Thought I had already posted.  That got things working, after a fashion.